# PowerShell not recognizing build.ps1 file. How to define the path with out hardcoding it

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have simple yml file for running a pipeline in Azure devops.
In the YML I have defined the .build.ps1 file path but I keep getting this error

../build.ps1 : The term '../build.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

here is where my build.ps1 file is ‪C:\Users\David.Remin\source\repos\branchName\FirstBranch\build.ps1

here is how I defined in the yml file

powershell: ../build.ps1

I do not want to hard code file path.. As this will be different everytime. I just want to mention the file name

```yaml
#This is the YML file

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- powershell: .\build.ps1 -target=Push -nugetUsername='$(nugetUsername)' -nugetPassword='$(nugetPassword)'
```

Comment: Without seeing the code this is rather difficult. If you're in a powershell script, in order to call an external powershell script you have to treat it like any other external script and use `Start-process`. However, for ease of reading, its typically written as `& .\build.ps1'`. Does this help?

Comment: Which code.. YML file?                                                                                                 
 I have changed it to .buildps1 but I get the same error                                       
The term '.\build.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Can you post your YML code? There are a couple of ways to define this and it will help to see what you currently have.

Comment: sure I posted it

Comment: You keep spelling the name of the build file differently, can you write out the **exact** name it has? For instance, does it have a dot in front of ps1? (your comment indicates it hasn't), does it have a dot at the start (your question says both, your comment says yes). Basically, which of these is the right one? `.buildps1`, `.build.ps1`, `build.ps1` ?

Comment: @KevinDavis965 Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to push your `build.ps1` file to Azure devops repo.

If you want to run the local build .ps1 file, first you need to specify the [private agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#choosing-a-pool-and-agent-in-your-pipeline) instead of the Hosted agent pool. Second, you need to specify the `workingDirectory` argument of the powershell task in the yaml, otherwise the default is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

`workingDirectory`:Specify the working directory in which you want to run the command. If you leave it empty, the working directory is $(Build.SourcesDirectory). For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops).

You can refer to the following sample script:

```
pool: Default
       
jobs:
- job: Build   

  steps:
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
          filePath: 'build.ps1'
          workingDirectory: 'C:\Users\David.Remin\source\repos\branchName\FirstBranch'
          arguments: '-target=Push -nugetUsername='$(nugetUsername)' -nugetPassword='$(nugetPassword)'
```